# Checking String is a Palindrome Case Insensitive in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a string is a Palindrome (case insensitive) in Haskell. To make sure capital case characters don't cause an issue, I first convert the string to lower case with `toLower` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:toLower). Then I check if that is equal to the reversed version of the same thing. Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text (toLower)


isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = toLower xs == toLower $ reverse xs
```

I realized `toLower` uses Text instead of String and we need to use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to overload String to Text. But this does not compile.

I replicated this in GHCI as well. I first used `:set -XOverloadedStrings` to make sure to overload strings. Then I run this:

```
Prelude Data.Text> toLower $ reverse "sdssSDSS"

<interactive>:92:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘reverse "sdssSDSS"’
      In the expression: toLower $ reverse "sdssSDSS"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = toLower $ reverse "sdssSDSS"
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. If I first run `reverse "sdssSDSS"` and copy paste the result into `toLower` it works without an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and we need to use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to overload `String` to `Text`

no. That extension should arguably be called `OverloadedStringLiterals`. It only changes the behaviour of *literals* such as `"hello"` or `"sdssSDSS"`, but doesn't convert between `String` and `Text` otherwise. Generally, automatic conversion *never* happen in Haskell, all that happens is that you can have polymorphic values, like numerical literals or string literals with that extension.

In modern Haskell, probably the best option is just to write it all in `Text` and never introduce `String` at all:

```
import qualified Data.Text as Txt

isPalindrome :: Txt.Text -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = Txt.toLower xs == Txt.toLower (Txt.reverse xs)
```

(note that you can't use `$` there, because it has lower precedence than `==`).

But you don't *need* to use `Text` at all, there's also single-character version of `toLower`:

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = map toLower xs == map toLower (reverse xs)
```

BTW, in both cases it would be possible to use `toLower` only once:

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = xsLC == reverse xsLC
 where xsLC = map toLower xs
```

Comment: Shouldn't `where xsLC = map toLower xsLC`  be replaced by `where xsLC = map toLower xs` ?

Comment: For `String`, you only need to compare the first ``n `quot` 2`` to the last ``n `quot` 2`` ones. For `Text`, I would think a full `reverse` might be overkill. I'm thinking walk the byte array with two pointers. The tortoise copies into a fresh array about half the length of the original. When the hare reaches the end, ignore any middle `Char` and compare the reversed front to the rear.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not going to spend mental resources on optimising a problem that is clearly of no value except educational.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you for the explanation. Although I don't understand why $ can't be used in this context. As far as I've understood, it is the same as putting parentheses around what comes after $. Is there a distinction between the two?

Comment: @C.Acarbay It is (basically) the same as putting parentheses around both what comes after **and before** the `$`. I.e. `x == f $ y+z` is parsed as `(x == f) (y+z)`.

Answer (score 2):

leftaroundabout has already explained to you how to solve your problem but I have one small addition. If you want to use regular Char -> Char functions with a Text type, you can easily do it using Lens and [unpacked](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Lens.html#v:unpacked) ISO (it's convenient but slow :)).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Text as T

useFun1 :: (String -> String) -> T.Text -> T.Text
useFun1 = over unpacked

useFun2 :: (Char -> Char) -> T.Text -> T.Text
useFun2 = over (unpacked . traversed)
```